# Debugging a YUI Javascript error

Tags: javascript, widget, yui

I am working on making a widget that uses a YUI Javascript library to render a hike map, a trailhead and the route.  Here is the example of what I am trying to do

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?hike_id=108&height=600&width=700

But if you look at the JS error console, it is complaining about offsetWidth variable being undefined.  I am a bit stuck in how to debug this.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting that complaint, I am getting others (using Safari).

Comment: @sergio what errors are you getting?

Comment: result of 'a' expression undefined; at main,geometry.js:30

Answer (score 0):

This question answers this question nicely: [How to disable YUI2 silent failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231828/how-to-disable-yui-silent-failing)

```
YAHOO.widget.Logger.enableBrowserConsole();
YAHOO.util.Event.throwErrors = true;
```